# Как определить, сколько элементов содержит массив в Java?

Tags: java, массивы

Как определить, сколько элементов содержит массив в [java](/questions/tagged/java)?

Comment: посмотреть в `array.length`.

Comment: @Nofate, почему не ответом?

Answer (score 7):

В Java у массивов есть свойство **length**, которое содержит его длину. Это
свойство доступно только для чтения и позволяет узнать количество элементов в
одномерном массиве.

```
Object[] array = { ... };
System.out.println(array.length);
```

---

Чтобы выяснить количество элементов в двумерном массиве в Java 8 предлагается
воспользоваться интерфейсом потоков.

```
Object[][] array = { ... };
int count = Stream.of(array).mapToInt(m -> m.length).sum();
System.out.println(count);
```

В более ранних версиях придётся устраивать цикл, в котором суммируются длины
всех подмассивов в переданном аргументе.

```
public static int count(Object[][] array) {
    int result = 0;
    for (Object[] m : array) {
        result += m.length;
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

Стоит заметить, что для вычисления длины строки используется метод **length**,
не свойство (т.е. нужно писать скобочки), а для вычисления длины любой коллекции
применяется метод **size**.

```
String s = "...";
System.out.println(s.length());

Set<Integer> s = new TreeSet<Integer>();
s.add(...);
System.out.println(s.size());
```

Comment: Если размерность массива заранее неизвестна, я пока не нашёл элегантного решения...

Answer (score 1):

Самый примитивный вариант. Например так:

```
public class ExampleArrayLenght {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arrays = {"one", "two", "three"};
    int arrayLength = arrays.length;
    System.out.println("Длинна массива = " + arrayLength + " элемента.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для определения размера массива нужно использовать свойство `length`.

```
int[] array = {1, -4, 3, 5};
int length = array.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Если используется Лист:

```
public int countArr(List<Integer> arr){
    return (int) arr.stream().count();
}
```

Или:

```
public int countArr(List<Integer> arr){
       return arr.size();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int rows = array.length;
int cols = array[0].length;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]